# string builder and dictionary

Tags: asp.net

can i add string builder object  to a dictionary object?
If yes please code it.

i mean i have a dictionary in which i have already added a few (string, objects),
And i have a string Builder which has few variable already added now i want that instead of passing 2 different object in a method i want to pass only one object so can i add string builder object to same method as well

Comment: What are we trying to do or achieve here?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what exactly you're trying to do, rather than saying "please code it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a StringBuilder to a `Dictionary<K,V>` object, but as it's a Dictionary, you will need a key.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Dictionary<string, StringBuilder> dict = new Dictionary<string, StringBuilder>();
dict.Add("MyFirstStringBuilder", sb);
```

Comment: if in my string builder i have more than one items can i access all those using single key "MyFirstStringBuilder"

Comment: The string builder itself doesn't have 'items', but if you mean you have many string builders, you would have to add them with different keys:
dict.Add("MySecondStringBuilder", sb2) etc.
You could then get them back out like this:
StringBuilder secondStringBuilder = dict["MySecondStringBuilder"];

Answer (score 2):

You can do it, but as others said in the comments if you explain your purpose that would be nice.

```
Dictionary<string,StringBuilder> dic = new Dictionary<string,StringBuilder>();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("value");
dic["key"]=sb;
```